# Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.XMLSchemaMessages

Tags: java, deployment, jenkins, glassfish, jenkins-plugins

I have a web application and using jenkins for build and deployment to glassfish 3+ server. But now I am facing a problem. The jenkins is building the application successfully but when it tries to deploy the application to the target server then it failed with following error

Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Gordon Converter Dev/target/gordons-dev-deployment.war to container GlassFish 3.x Remote

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Deployment has failed: Action failed Deploying application to target server failed; Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [gordons-dev-deployment] : Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.XMLSchemaMessages. Please see server.log for more details.
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.waitForProgressObject(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:220)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.deploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:76)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:142)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:920)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:893)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:756)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1040)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:669)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
```

Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 2):

I just got this error too and I noticed that Java had auto updated itself to the latest version.  So I was compiling the application with Java 1.7.0_131, but Glassfish3 was still running under Java 1.7.0_121.  My solution was to restart Glassfish so that it was running under the new version of Java 1.7.0_131.  I guess I could have also downgraded my Java back to 1.7.0_121 and compiled my application with that... Bottom line here is to make sure that you are compiling with the same version of Java that Glassfish is running.